# Where does the function Argument comes from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently confused, where a argument is coming from. Because for my understanding I don't implizite pass it anywhere.

Could someone maybe explain how to understand this example ? Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import FormatAlignLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignLeft';
import FormatAlignCenterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignCenter';
import FormatAlignRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignRight';
import FormatAlignJustifyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignJustify';
import ToggleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup';

export default function ToggleButtons() {
  const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState('left');

  const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
  };

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      value={alignment}
      exclusive
      onChange={handleAlignment}
      aria-label="text alignment"
    >
      <ToggleButton value="left" aria-label="left aligned">
        <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="center" aria-label="centered">
        <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="right" aria-label="right aligned">
        <FormatAlignRightIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="justify" aria-label="justified" disabled>
        <FormatAlignJustifyIcon />
      </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

To narrow it further down:
The **newAlignment** argument is the one that confuses me.

```
...

  const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
  };

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToggleButtonGroup` component handles this internally. It basically does something in a way of the example below. **Note: this is pseudo code, not how it actually works.**

```
const ToggleButtonGroup = ({ onChange, children }) => {
  const handleInternalOnChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    onChange(event, value); // Both the event and the value is passed.
  };

  return (
    <div onChange={handleInternalOnChange}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
};
```

So `ToggleButtonGroup` wraps the `onChange` function and handles the *original* event, getting the values from it, before passing both the `event` and the `value` to your  `onChange` handler.

Comment: This is where they do it:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/13138c834bed8ee3843ad29df345cd71d2834daf/packages/material-ui-lab/src/ToggleButtonGroup/ToggleButtonGroup.js#L62

Comment: Thank you @Emiel Zuurbier. You explained it perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`ToggleButtonGroup` component has an has a `value` and an `onChange` property. When the component changes, it passes it's `event` and `alignment` value to your handler that you provided; in this case `handleAlignment`.